# T-SQL - Use Bitwise operation to find missing values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

A sample data table within the database.

It's missing some days from each ID1/ID2 combo group

```
DECLARE @Week_DataTable TABLE 
    (
        [ID1]      INT
      , [ID2]      INT
      , [Day_Enum] INT
      , [IsActive] BIT DEFAULT ( 0 )
    ) ;

INSERT INTO @Week_DataTable
    (
        [ID1]
      , [ID2]
      , [Day_Enum]
      , [IsActive]
    )
VALUES
    ( 1, 1, 1, 0 )
  , ( 1, 1, 2, 0 )
  , ( 1, 1, 3, 0 )
  , ( 1, 1, 4, 0 )
  , ( 1, 1, 5, 0 )
  , ( 1, 1, 6, 0 )
  , ( 1, 1, 7, 0 )

  , ( 1, 2, 1, 0 )

  , ( 1, 2, 3, 0 )
  , ( 1, 2, 4, 0 )
  , ( 1, 2, 5, 0 )
  , ( 1, 2, 6, 0 )

  , ( 1, 3, 1, 0 )
  , ( 1, 3, 2, 0 )
  , ( 1, 3, 3, 0 )
  , ( 1, 3, 4, 0 )
  , ( 1, 3, 5, 0 )


  , ( 1, 4, 1, 0 )
  , ( 1, 4, 2, 0 )


  , ( 1, 4, 5, 0 )
  , ( 1, 4, 6, 0 )
  , ( 1, 4, 7, 0 ) ;

SELECT * FROM @Week_DataTable
```

A lookup table to find missing days from @Week_DataTable where [Validate] = 1
Join key field = [Day_Enum] field
Bitwise logic (field = [Code]) should be used to find missing days in @Week_DataTable

```
   DECLARE @Days TABLE
    (
        [Day_Id]   INT        NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
      , [Day_Enum] INT        NOT NULL
      , [Day_Name] VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL
      , [Code]     INT        NOT NULL DEFAULT ( 0 )
      , [Validate] BIT        NOT NULL DEFAULT ( 1 )
    ) ;

INSERT INTO @Days
    (
        [Day_Enum]
      , [Day_Name]
      , [Code]
      , [Validate]
    )
SELECT  [V].[Day_Enum]
      , [V].[Day_Name]
      , [V].[Code]
      , [V].[Validate]
FROM    (
            VALUES
                ( 1, 'Monday', 1, 0 )
              , ( 2, 'Tuesday', 2, 0 )
              , ( 3, 'Wednesday', 4, 0 )
              , ( 4, 'Thursday', 8, 0 )
              , ( 5, 'Friday', 16, 0 )
              , ( 6, 'Saturday', 32, 1 )
              , ( 7, 'Sunday', 64, 1 )
        ) [V] ( [Day_Enum], [Day_Name], [Code], [Validate] ) ;

SELECT  *
FROM    @Days ;
```

Goal: to query missing days in `@Week_DataTable` table by using `@Days` lookup table `where [Validate] = 1`. Bitwise operation must be used ([Code]) for this operation.

Update: sorry, forgot to include the desired output earlier. Also added the reason behind [Valid] flag.
Desired Output

```
ID1 ID2 Day_Enum    IsActive
1   1   1   0
1   1   2   0
1   1   3   0
1   1   4   0
1   1   5   0
1   1   6   0
1   1   7   0
1   2   1   0

1   2   3   0
1   2   4   0
1   2   5   0
1   2   6   0
1   2   7   0
1   3   1   0
1   3   2   0
1   3   3   0
1   3   4   0
1   3   5   0
1   3   6   0
1   3   7   0
1   4   1   0
1   4   2   0


1   4   5   0
1   4   6   0
1   4   7   0
```

Valid flag indicates which missing day(s) should the query find. If Valid is only true for Sat/Sun, the query should find all missing Sat/Sun from the data table.

Comment: Please add some example query. How would it determine that day is "missing". And why are you mentioning bitwise operations whereas you already have `day_id` and `day_enum` is even in both tables. No idea how are those `code` bit masks related to the task described.

Comment: Bitwise operation must be used. Why?

Comment: What do you want the _missing_ values to look like? A list of day names? A bitmask?  Poetry?

Comment: You could not just insert the values directly into @days?  Why must you use bitwise?  Why is [ID2] even needed for this question?  This is homework right?

Comment: sry guys, forgot to copy the desired output from xl and include it in op. Added! The goal is to use bitwise to come up with a solution (yes, the result can be obtained by simply using joins, but the requirement is to use bitwise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the purpose of the bit flags. While I supposed you can sum them, assuming there are no duplicates per day, it doesn't really make it easier to decode the aggregate value and pull out missing days. Is this along the lines of what you're thinking?

```
select ID1, ID2, sum(Code),
    replace('Missing:' +
      case when sum(Code) & 0x01 = 0 then ', Monday'    else '' end +
      case when sum(Code) & 0x02 = 0 then ', Tuesday'   else '' end +
      case when sum(Code) & 0x04 = 0 then ', Wednesday' else '' end +
      case when sum(Code) & 0x08 = 0 then ', Thursday'  else '' end +
      case when sum(Code) & 0x10 = 0 then ', Friday'    else '' end +
      case when sum(Code) & 0x20 = 0 then ', Saturday'  else '' end +
      case when sum(Code) & 0x40 = 0 then ', Sunday'    else '' end, ':,', ':') as Summary

from @Week_DataTable w inner join @Days d on d.Day_Enum = w.Day_Enum
group by ID1, ID2
having sum(Code) < (select sum(Code) from @Days); -- or just 127
```

**EDIT:** Based on your edit I think you're just looking for a standard densifying query. I still don't see the necessity for bit operations.

```
with combos as (select ID1, ID2 from @Week_DataTable group by ID1, ID2),
    days as (select * from @Days where Valid = 1)
select
from combos c cross join days d
    left outer join @Week_DataTable w
        on w.ID1 = c.ID1 and w.ID2 = c.ID2 and w.Day_Enum = d.Day_Enum
where w.Day_Enum is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what you want to do with `Validate`, but I expect that it can easily be incorporated in the following code samples.

You can gather up the bitmask for the included days using `sum`:

```
-- Get a bitmask of days for each Id1/Id2 pair.
select WDT.ID1, WDT.ID2, Sum( D.Code ) as BitMask
  from @Week_DataTable as WDT inner join
    @Days as D on D.Day_Enum = WDT.Day_Enum
  group by WDT.ID1, WDT.ID2;
```

The omitted days are easily produced using exclusive-or:

```
-- Get missing days for each Id1/Id2 pair.
select WDT.ID1, WDT.ID2, 127 ^ Sum( D.Code ) as OmittedBitMask
  from @Week_DataTable as WDT inner join
    @Days as D on D.Day_Enum = WDT.Day_Enum
  group by WDT.ID1, WDT.ID2;
```

The results can be presented as a table of missing days by checking each bit:

```
-- Get missing days for each Id1/Id2 pair by day.
with OmittedDays as (
  select WDT.ID1, WDT.ID2, 127 ^ Sum( D.Code ) as OmittedBitMask
    from @Week_DataTable as WDT inner join
      @Days as D on D.Day_Enum = WDT.Day_Enum
    group by WDT.ID1, WDT.ID2 )
  select *
    from OmittedDays as OD inner join
      @Days as D on D.Code & OD.OmittedBitMask = D.Code
    order by OD.ID1, OD.ID2, D.Day_Enum;
```